# How to 'close/ mark as resolved' my question I have found an answer to?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question about an error I was facing. After much toil, I somehow failed to resolve it. But once I posted it, I spotted the syntax error in a few minutes.

So I want to close the question, so that I don't waste people's time who look at it. What should/can I do about it?

Comment: Once "typo" close vote cast, 4 more to go.

Comment: @Bart "Once "typo" close vote cast", I am sorry I don't get this. Can you please be a bit more clear? What is "close vote cast" or "typo close vote cast"?

Comment: That should have read "one". There is a specific close reason for typos and the like. I located your question and voted to close it as such. *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."*.

Comment: @Bart can I vote to close your 'Once "typo" close' comment due to a typo?

Comment: You can do whatever you onced ... wans ... want @Humdinger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the question is truly a matter of incorrect syntax and you feel that it won't benefit the wider community then you can delete the question **as long as it has no upvoted answers**.

Otherwise a vote to close with the:

> "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.".

reason is all you can do.

If you think that there might be some use in leaving the question then add the resolution as an answer which you can accept after a couple of days. This will effectively mark the problem as "resolved".